# How to disable dates and days in jquery datepicker. But Both functionality not working simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

// Day and Dates( Both functionality not working simultaneously)

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var datestring = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        if (datestring != '') {
            return [disableddates.indexOf(datestring) == -1];
        }
        <?php if(isset($delivery_date_setting -> delivery_days_sunday) 
                 && $delivery_date_setting ->delivery_days_sunday == '1') { ?>

        if (date.getDay() == 0) {
            return [true, ''];
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I suggest you to improve your question by reading the [Minimal, Complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand, You want to Disable some dates that are inside an string array having dates in format

`['2015-12-01', '2015-12-02', '2015-12-03']`

also want to disable the first day (Sunday) for certain conditions

Try the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mayanksaxena19/k36q6fc4/1/),

```
var disableddates = ['2015-12-01', '2015-12-02', '2015-12-03'];

function DisableSpecificDates(date) {
  var datestring = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
  var disableDate = 0;
  if ($.inArray(datestring, disableddates) != -1) {
    disableDate++;
  }
  if (date.getDay() == 0) {
    disableDate++;
  }
  if (disableDate > 0)
    return [false];
  else
    return [true];
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#datepickerctrl').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates
  });
});
```

Hope it works for you